# StackOverflowError when removing node with 2 children on Binary Tree

Tags: java, tree

Trying to create a binary tree to be used in a system for storing strings. Currently the tree works for adding, and confirming whether words exist. I'm hitting a stack overflow error when removing a node with 2 children. It's inconsistent, as it sometimes works and sometimes gives error, so I can't pinpoint a cause.

Currently the code takes a string, gets a hash from it to use as a reference for the tree, if the count is higher than one, removes one, otherwise checks to see what children the node has.

```
public void removeNode(String str)
{
    int hash = str.hashCode();
    if(hash==contentID)
    {
        if(count>1)
        {
            count--;
            //System.out.println("Counter decreased");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!hasChild())
            {
                if(parent.left==this)
                {
                    parent.left=null;
                    //System.out.println("Object removed (No child)");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.right = null;
                }
            }
            else if(hasOneChild())
            {
                if(parent.left==this)
                {
                    if(left==null)
                    {
                        parent.left = right;
                        //System.out.println("Object removed (One child)");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent.left = left;
                        //System.out.println("Object removed (One child)");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(left==null)
                    {
                        parent.right = right;
                        //System.out.println("Object removed (One child)");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent.right = left;
                        //System.out.println("Object removed (One child)");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //This is where I believe the error is, somewhere within this else block

                Node HLS = findHighestLeftValue();

                //HLS Parent operations
                Node HLSParent = HLS.parent;
                HLSParent.right = HLS.left;
                HLSParent.right.parent = HLSParent;

                HLS.right = this.right;
                HLS.left = this.left;
                HLS.parent = this.parent;

                if(this.parent == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Root node");
                }
                else if(parent.right == this)
                {
                    parent.right = HLS;
                }
                else if(parent.left ==this)
                {
                    parent.left = HLS;
                }

                System.out.println("Object removed (2 children)");

                return;

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(hash>contentID)
        {
            try {
                right.removeNode(str);
                return;
            }
            catch(NullPointerException npe)
            {
                //System.out.println("Object not found to remove");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                left.removeNode(str);
                return;
            }
            catch(NullPointerException npe)
            {
                //System.out.println("Object not found to remove");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line the Stack Trace points to is

```
            try {
                left.removeNode(str);
                return;
            }
```

Why is this causing a stack overflow error?

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to try to work it out? (Note that you should pretty much *never* be catching NullPointerException - write your code to protect against it being thrown instead.)

Comment: I have debugged it, but there's nothing I can see. The NullPointer catches are there for when it has reached the end of the tree without finding what it is being searched for, meaning it doesn't exist in the tree. Currently this is still a WIP, and I'm more concerned with the StackOverflow at the moment. Later on, I will remove the NullPointer and replace it by throwing an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: If you've debugged into it, you should be able to step through until either it throws the StackOverflowException, or you see it recursing more than you expect it to. It doesn't help that you've only provided a snippet rather than a [mcve].